# Is this the correct way to make an axios GET request with react redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios, redux-thunk

I am a beginner and all of this is very new. I have been debugging for a while now and I can't seem to fix the bug. I would appreciate some pointers.

The other posts and put requests are working, but i get an proxy error(Could not proxy request /api/users/userdata from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/. (ECONNREFUSED)) when i try to do a get request.

This is a snippet of the props in Home using React Developer Tools Component Tab:
[props of Home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAMSx.png)

Action types for redux: **client\src\actions\types.js**

```
export const GET_ERRORS = "GET_ERRORS";

export const USER_LOADING = "USER_LOADING";
export const SET_CURRENT_USER = "SET_CURRENT_USER";

export const GET_USERDATA = "GET_USERDATA";
export const UPDATE_USERDATA = "UPDATE_USERDATA";
```

Actions for redux: **client\src\actions\userdataActions.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

import {
    GET_ERRORS,
    GET_USERDATA,
    UPDATE_USERDATA
} from "./types";

// Get userdata with username
export const getUserData = (userData) => dispatch => {
    return axios
        .get("/api/users/userdata", userData)
        .then(response => {
            dispatch(fetchUserData(response.data)); 
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch(getErrors(err));
        });
};

// Put new userdata with username
export const updateUserData = (newUserData) => dispatch => {
    axios
        .put("/api/users/userdata", newUserData)
        .then(response => {
            dispatch(updatingUserData());
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch(getErrors(err));
        });
};

export const fetchUserData = userData => {
    return {
        type: GET_USERDATA,
        payload: userData
    }
};

export const updatingUserData = () => {
    return {
        type: UPDATE_USERDATA
    };
};

// Get Errors 
export const getErrors = err => {
    return {
      type: GET_ERRORS,
      payload: err.response.data
    };
};
```

Reducers for redux: **client\src\reducers\dataReducers.js**

```
import {
    GET_USERDATA, 
    UPDATE_USERDATA
} from "../actions/types";

const isEmpty = require("is-empty");

const initialState = {
    hasUserData: false,
    user: {},
    updated: false,
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_USERDATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                hasUserData: !isEmpty(action.payload),
                user: action.payload
            };
        case UPDATE_USERDATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                updated: true,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

frontend using react: **client\src\components\home\Home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { logoutUser } from "../../actions/authActions";
import { getUserData, updateUserData } from "../../actions/userdataActions";

import Logout from "./Logout.js";
import Coins from "./Coins.js";
import Happiness from "./Happiness.js";

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.name = this.props.auth.user.name;
        this.updateCoins = this.updateCoins.bind(this);
        this.updateHappiness = this.updateHappiness.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (!this.props.userdata.hasUserData) {
            const userData = { name: this.name };
            this.props.getUserData(userData); 
        }  
    }

    onLogoutClick = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.logoutUser();
    };    

    updateCoins(newCoins) {
        const userData = {
            name: this.name,
            coins: newCoins,
        };
        this.props.updateUserData(userData); 
    }

    updateHappiness(newHappiness) {
        const userData = {
            name: this.name,
            happiness: newHappiness,
        };
        this.props.updateUserData(userData); 
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>  
                <Coins coins={this.props.userdata.user.coins} updateCoins={this.updateCoins} />
                <Happiness happiness={this.props.userdata.user.happiness} updateHappiness={this.updateHappiness} />
                <Logout onLogoutClick={this.onLogoutClick} />           
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Home.propTypes = {
    logoutUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    getUserData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    updateUserData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    userdata: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth,
    errors: state.errors,
    userdata: state.userdata
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { logoutUser,
      getUserData,
      updateUserData }
)(Home);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use ajax service like that. Instead

1. Use a service module to encapsulate all ajax calls and handle exceptions. Results of these services are Promises with raw data
2. In your thunk actions, then use the services to get data and dispatch to update store if necessary
3. Components just use thunk actions as normal.
   This helps increase separation of concerns, easier to test and maintain.

```
const handleError = (error) => {
   console.log(error);
};

export const getUserData = (userData) => {
    return axios
        .get("/api/users/userdata", userData)
        .then(response => (response.data))
        .catch(err => {
            handleError(err);
        });
};

...
// later in thunk action creator 

const updateUserDataThunk = async (userData) => dispatch => {
    const apiData = await getUserData(userData);
    dispatch(updateUser(apiData));
}

...
// in component

componentDidMount(){
  dispatch(updateUserDataThunk(this.props.userData));
}
```

Comment: can you put this into code - in context of the question?

Comment: Can u explain why you chose to use async await for the thunk action as opposed to promises?

Comment: I would also like to send the errors to the frontend to display it. How i can do it with this modified code structure?

Comment: For promise, I think async provides a cleaner way to reason about the code, you can use promise, it can produce same result
For sending errors to frontend to display, service can create another wrapper object for the `apiData` that can contain some normalized error message. Usually I don't see we need to display raw network error messages.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I will try it out.